# Can the traffic spew in bluetoothctl's interactive mode be turned off?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

This is an embarrassing question. I am ashamed to be asking it here. But since the command has no man page, installs with no documentation, and there is f-all for enduser resources at bluez.org, here I am. The question is somewhat different from other, previous questions regarding `bluetoothctl`, in that it's not so much about how to use it to achieve some device-related goal, and more about... just, how to *use* it, **period**.

`bluetoothctl` has two modes of operation:

1. A command-line mode, where you issue commands like `bluetoothctl pair <some device MAC>` or `bluetoothctl discoverable-timeout 300` or whatever, and get immediate results.
2. An interactive mode, where you run `bluetoothctl` to start it and are dropped into an interactive, shell-like prompt where commands can be issued and results shown.

It's that second mode that I'm trying to make useful. My **problem** is (and you'll see in a second why it's a problem) that I live in an apartment building where there's a fair amount of "ambient" bluetooth traffic constantly being picked up by my adapter's radio. I also already have a working, paired bluetooth mouse, which I use as my sole pointing device on the system.

Because that mouse and the other devices are all there, and because of the way `bluetoothctl` apparently works, anytime I run the command and get dropped into the interactive prompt, I *also* trigger a **CONSTANT** spew of traffic messages being scrolled onto the screen.

Within a second or two of my running the command, my terminal looks like this:

(I've randomly replaced all occurrences of multiple MAC digits with an asterisk, which should be enough to avoid any privacy issues. Only two of those devices are even *mine*, anyway.)

```
$ bluetoothctl
[CHG] Device 7*:*4:4*:1B:11:70 RSSI: -*8
[CHG] Device 74:78:D*:*2:*0:2* RSSI: -81
[CHG] Device **:02:*0:9*:**:B7 RSSI: -*3
[CHG] Device 2*:*9:9D:**:92:BD RSSI: -74
[CHG] Device 7*:*4:4*:1B:11:70 RSSI: -83
[CHG] Device B8:78:2*:2C:D4:1* RSSI: -*8
[CHG] Device **:02:*0:9*:**:B7 RSSI: -*3
[CHG] Device B8:78:2*:2C:D4:1* RSSI: -72
[CHG] Device 2C:41:*1:**:D2:2* RSSI: -*0
[CHG] Device **:02:*0:9*:**:B7 RSSI: -*2
[CHG] Device B8:78:2*:2C:D4:1* RSSI: -*9
[CHG] Device 10:2B:41:48:**:0* RSSI: -7*
[CHG] Device 2*:*9:9D:**:92:BD RSSI: -81
[CHG] Device 74:78:D*:*2:*0:2* RSSI: -82
[CHG] Device 78:*D:*B:97:**:74 RSSI: -89
[CHG] Device 78:*D:*B:97:**:74 ManufacturerData Key: 0x0211
[CHG] Device 78:*D:*B:97:**:74 ManufacturerData Value:
  11 22 74 *f 97 eb                                ."t_..          
[CHG] Device 78:*D:*B:97:**:74 ManufacturerData Key: 0x3*b0
[CHG] Device 78:*D:*B:97:**:74 ManufacturerData Value:
  01 c4 41 *9 c9 04 f9 a9 07 1* 03 f0 fd 81 *8 02  ..*i..........h.
  b0 a0 9* *0 04 f9 09 dc 1e f* 12                 ...`.......     
[CHG] Device **:02:*0:9*:**:B7 RSSI: -*3
[CHG] Device 2*:*9:9D:**:92:BD RSSI: -81
[CHG] Device 74:78:D*:*2:*0:2* RSSI: -83
[CHG] Device 7*:*4:4*:1B:11:70 RSSI: -70
[CHG] Device 2*:*9:9D:**:92:BD RSSI: -80
[CHG] Device B8:78:2*:2C:D4:1* RSSI: -**
[CHG] Device 10:2B:41:48:**:0* RSSI: -74
[CHG] Device 7*:*4:4*:1B:11:70 RSSI: -*8
[CHG] Device B8:78:2*:2C:D4:1* RSSI: -72
[CHG] Device 10:2B:41:48:**:0* RSSI: -74
[mouse]#
```

And it is ***relentless***. So much so, that anytime I type an interactive command, the output it produces is scrolled offscreen before I even have a chance to read it!

Without a man page, and with the interactive mode effectively inaccessible, I can't get enough information out of the tool to figure out: **Is there any way to *shut that traffic spew UP* so that I might be able to actually make use of the interactive shell?**

Comment: This is a cross-site duplicate of [How to disable bluetooth continuously scan devices on Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1277052/1110856).

Comment: @questionto42 Well, considering I'm on Fedora, it's kind of really not. (Or, more to the point: that other question is misplaced since it really had nothing to do with Ubuntu specifically.)

Comment: Good point. They often put it on Ask Ubuntu SE when it should be on Unix & Linux SE or here instead.

Comment: (They are _both_ 100% dupes of this one, though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991324/reduce-bluetoothctl-verbosity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the post
[Reduce bluetoothctl verbosity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991324/reduce-bluetoothctl-verbosity),
this
[answer by Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70583502/165358)
may pertain to your case :

> These change entries reporting signal strength (RSSI) show up if you ask **bluetoothctl** to scan for devices with `scan on`. Turning on scanning may happen also inadvertently if you have your `gnome-control-center bluetooth` GUI open as well, which is continuously scanning for devices.

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed that one when I was searching. This is probably a duplicate, technically. Typing `scan off` / closing `gnome-control-center` (as appropriate) does work. Though if the issue is g-c-c, even typing `scan off` **doesn't** stop the spew. It's still insane to me that that's how it works, but whatever.

Comment: Worked for me only by closing the Bluetooth menu. `scan off` did not help. As in the remark above.

Comment: `scan off` did not have an effect (but did not throw an error either). It then worked for me only by closing the Bluetooth menu. As in the remark above. I am now not sure whether I needed the command as well. Someone else should check this without the command and tell.

Comment: @questionto42 If the issue is that scanning has been enabled because the desktop is scanning (either because gnome-control-center or a Bluetooth menu is open), then you don't need to type `scan off` because closing that GUI implicitly ends scanning. An explicit `scan off` is only necessary if the reason for scanning being active is that you previously typed `scan on`.