# How to use bluetoothctl effectively?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, iot, bluez

When using bluetoothctl, it seems necessary to run the command `scan on` before it will connect to a low energy (IoT) device. I know the MAC of the device, but attempting to connect to it directly always fails with a `Device xx:xx:xx not available` error message. Within 1-3 seconds of turning on `scan on`, it becomes possible to connect to the device. But as soon as `scan off` is run, the device immediately disconnects.

While running, I receive an onslaught of `[CHG] Device xx:xx:xx` and `[NEW] Device xx:xx:xx` messages. I work in an office building with apparently dozens to hundreds of devices occasionally within the max distance. Not all of the CHG messages are rssi, but even if they were [the other guy's question failed to provide helpful answers](https://superuser.com/questions/1777137/). It was just a link to StackOverflow that pointed out they were rssi messages, without suggesting how to suppress them. I can't not `scan on` because the tool fails to work otherwise.

This tool is barely usable, and I have no idea why anyone thought this was good design. It must have been created when there were very few extant bt devices.

#### Additional information

I've figured out how to filter out some of the rssi messages. It's a simple enough command(s):

```
menu scan
rssi X
back
scan on
```

(Where X is an integer, usually negative, below which you will see no messages.)

The problem being that if I set this to a value high enough that I suppress all rssi messages, including the device I'm targeting, it's no longer possible to connect to the device. I can choose a number that suppresses most messages, but if the rssi messages for the device won't show up, then it's cock-blocked.

Did they design this tool just to make it unusable within a shell/expect script? This is just fucked.

I've had more luck suppressing the other messages. Once in the scan menu, you can do `pattern <MAC>` where the MAC is either the full MAC of the device, or a partal/prefix.